# split and drop pandas dataframe by label

Tags: python, pandas

how can i split dataframe equally from the least of all?

suppose that i have total of 625 data (300 spam, 325 not spam)

so i have to drop those 25 **random** not spam and make it 300 spam and 300 not spam

important  :

im using pandas library

the total of the data is not fixed

ratio of spam and not spam data is not fixed

what im at right now:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('directory/dataset.csv')
df[label].value_counts() #show total spam, total not spam
```

here is the header of my dataframe :

| sentence | label |
| --- | --- |
| FU bro | spam |
| Well thats kinda cool | not spam |
| Haha thats so funny | not spam |
| cant u make somethin else mtfk | spam |
| what a shame | spam |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach would use [pd.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to reduce each label row count to the minimum label count and concatenate the results back together.  This should also work for any number of labels.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': {0: 'FU bro',
  1: 'Well thats kinda cool',
  2: 'Haha thats so funny',
  3: 'cant u make somethin else mtfk',
  4: 'what a shame'},
 'label': {0: 'spam', 1: 'not spam', 2: 'not spam', 3: 'spam', 4: 'spam'}})


df = pd.concat([df.loc[df['label']==l].sample(df.label.value_counts().min()) for l in df.label.unique()])

print(df)
```

Output

```
                         sentence     label
3  cant u make somethin else mtfk      spam
4                    what a shame      spam
2             Haha thats so funny  not spam
1           Well thats kinda cool  not spam
```

Comment: ive already tried this and its doesnt work. when i check the ```df['label'].value_counts```. it stays the same

Comment: @AnggiaBagaskara It works on the sample data you shared, what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: haha my bad that does work, i forgot to declare the df before the concate